# How do you map a word address to a block address?

Tags: memory-address

Given a fully associative cache that supports 2 word block size. LRU strategy.  Cache is empty. I have a word address sequence of lets say 0, 4, 11, 2, 13, 21, 22, 6, 10.  To determine the hits and misses do I convert this to binary and then because the offset is 3 do I drop the last 3 bits and this gets me what goes into the cache? And if it's 2 block size does that mean each block has 2 words in it so if I took the first part of this

```
0   0000 drop last 3 bits-> 0 MISS
4   0100 -> 0 HIT
11  1011 -> 1 MISS
2   0010 -> 0 HIT
13  1101 -> 1 HIT
21 10101 -> 10 MISS
22 10110 -> 10 HIT
6   0110 -> 0 HIT
10  1010 -> 1 HIT
```

So then does the newly converted number end up in the cache so all the misses would be: 1 0 2 or is it the original number: 0 11 21?

Any help is appreciated! Having trouble understanding how word addressable impacts the answer and a 2 block cache vs 1 block.